# How to get all column values in search results include pagination

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

This is example

```
id | name | year | color
------------------------
1  | john | 1955 | red
2  | mark | 1955 | yellow
.... more than 10K inserts
```

If I search for "mark" i got ~100 results. I show paginated results ( 15 per page).

What I want is: Show 15 result per page but on side show all distinct values for 'year' and 'color' which will used as filters based on all ~100 results.

In future there will be about 100K inserts and about 20 cells ( year, color) as filters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 15; 
$offest = $page * $count; 
// for the 1-st page $page = 0; 
// for the 2-nd page $page = 1; 
// for the 3-rd page $page = 2;  ......

SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = 'mark' 
GROUP BY year, color
LIMIT $offset, $count;
```